# Hide collection of controls based on condition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page, that has common controls at the top and the bottom of the page. (~75% of controls).
The rest of the controls are controlled by a condition of page_load.

So, I have, say: 30 controls And 5 conditions.
On page_Load, I have to do the following:

```
     if (condtion1)
       {
        control1.Visible=false;
        control2.Visible=true;
        control3.Visible=false;
        control4.Visible=true;
        ...etc...
       }
     else if (condition2)
      { contorl1.Visible=true;
        control2.Visible=true; 
        control3.Visible=true;
       ...etc...
      }
      ...etc....
```

Is there a better way to control control visiblity for multiple controls? Note that controls can overlap, i.e. condition1 and condition2 can have the same visible controls in common.

My Idea was to create 20 controls and have some kind of Panel where you can define what controls belong to this panel, but not sure if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer something like so:

```
control1.Visible = condition1;
control2.Visible = condition1 || condtion2;
control3.Visible = condition2;
```

You may be able to group the controls or conditions together to make your intent more obvious.

Comment: Jon, Thanks for your answer. Do you if there's anything pretty can be done if I also need to control order of the controls? They are all vertically aligned in one column. I was thinking to have some kind of descriptive XML that will store order and visibility of the controls for each condition. But I'm not sure if it is possible. Or maybe I should use completely separate forms?

Comment: @user194076 if you want to show/hide as well as reorder you might be better off generating controls on the fly instead of at design-time.